# Oracle Imp Dump Full

Tags: oracle, import

Can I create a new instance in a new server and import a dump file which was made with the command exp full=y etc?

If it is possible do I need to recreate tablespaces and users before the import? If yes can I find these two from the dump file alone?

Comment: Are you just looking for a Yes/No answer (which would be "yes").  Or is there more to your question?

Comment: Well if its possible I will do my research and try to make it happen! If you have any pointers to make my life easier I would be thankful though.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a full import, the import will attempt to create all the tablespaces and data files exactly as they existed in the source system.  If you want exactly the same data files on exactly the same locations, you're all set.  If you want the data files to be in different locations, you would need to create the tablespaces before doing the import.

If you do a full import, the import will create all the users.

Comment: Should i create the users first in the new db? That would be a problem since all i have is the dump file.

Comment: @Alexk - Updated my answer.

Comment: you will get a lot of error meassages and it will be hard to decide if they are important or can be ignored

Comment: @miracle173 - What errors are you referring to?  A full import should import cleanly assuming that you either want a physically identical database or that you properly pre-create the tablespaces with the new data files before running the import unless there were issues in the source database (i.e. objects that couldn't compile successfully in the source database) or where a non-consistent export was generated from a database that was still being actively used.

Comment: i will need some time to create an appropriate test case